# Creating triggers in oracle

Tags: oracle, triggers

Please help me to resolve the below problem

I need to Create a trigger named `trigger_contact_af_update` that is triggered whenever the "contact" table is updated. This trigger will insert the org_name and action into the table `contact_log_history` after the updation of contact details. The action name in the affected log table `contact_log_history` is `After_Update_Contact`.

Hints:
Trigger name : trigger_contact_af_update
Table name : contact_log_history
Field names : org_name,action
Action  : 'After_Update_Contact'.

The table structure of contact_log_history is as follows:
org_name varchar(30)
action varchar(30)

The table structure of contact is as follows:

id is the primary key in contact table

id              integer
org_name        varchar2(255)
street_address1 varchar2(255)
street_address2 varchar2(255)
city            varchar2(255)
state           varchar2(255)
postal_code     varchar2(255)
country_code    varchar2(255)
last_name       varchar2(255)
first_name      varchar2(255)
person_title    varchar2(255)
phone_country_code   integer
phone_area_code      integer
phone_number         varchar2(255)
email                varchar2(255)
created_time         timestamp

I have created the trigger as below, but while executing it is not returning any error message nor creating the trigger. Please let me know the error in the creation of trigger / the correct statement

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger_contact_af_update
AFTER UPDATE
   ON contact
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
BEGIN
INSERT INTO contact_log_history
   (org_name,
     action)
select org_name, 'contact_log_history' 
from contact 
END;
```

Comment: why you dont use only new updated value

Comment: @Stephia What version of Oracle do you use? How do you check whether the trigger is created or not? Did you try to run this select statement: `select * from user_triggers where trigger_name = 'TRIGGER_CONTACT_AF_UPDATE'` ?

Comment: @Stephia How do you run your `Create Trigger` statement? Which software do you use?

Comment: Using DBMS editor.. Nothing is displayed after executing the trigger statement. I tried "select * from user_triggers where trigger_name = 'TRIGGER_CONTACT_AF_UPDATE'" .. No rows selected on executing it,,

Comment: Any updates??Please help

Comment: Trigger created successfully after giving "/" after the END statement

Answer (score 2):

why you dont use only new updated value?
you can insert only updated new value `:new.org_name`, like this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger_contact_af_update AFTER UPDATE ON contact FOR EACH ROW 
DECLARE 
BEGIN 
INSERT INTO contact_log_history (org_name, action) values (:new.org_name, 'contact_log_history');
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use `:new` keyword. Also, you must add `;` at the end of `insert` statement. The corrected version of the trigger is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger_contact_af_update
AFTER UPDATE
   ON contact
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO contact_log_history
       (org_name, action)
    VALUES 
       (:new.org_name, 'contact_log_history');
END;
```

Comment: the `select from dual` is redundant in this scenario

Comment: Tried below 
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger_contact_af_update
AFTER UPDATE
   ON contact
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO contact_log_history
       (org_name, action)
    VALUES 
       (:new.org_name, 'contact_log_history');
END;

but trigger is not creating.. Is there any other syntax

Comment: @Stephia Would you please add DDL of `contact` and `contact_log_history` tables to the question?

Comment: The table structure of contact_log_history is as follows:
 org_name varchar(30),
 action varchar(30)

The table structure of contact table is
id   integer,
org_name varchar2(255),
street_address1 varchar2(255).,,,,,
and there are 13 other columns in contact table

Comment: @Stephia Edit your question and add complete tables structures there. Your problem may be related to structures.