# creating trigger on sql

Tags: sql, plsql, triggers

Schema :

> Std_report(sid, tid, sname, tname, sub1_mark, sub2_mark, sub3_mark,
> total_mark, avg_mark)

I want to create a trigger that will calculate the sum and average of the marks of the students once their subject mark were entered and stores the grade of each student.

PS:  I am using Oracle 11g

Comment: Have you tried the documentation? I'm assuming you're using MySQL? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: Hi, I am using Oracle 11 g

Comment: I'm afraid I've never used it so I can't be much help but I would start with looking through the documentation

Comment: @GoruChagol . . . Why bother with a trigger?  Just calculate the values when they are needed.

Comment: I must need to calculate the trigger in this case. Thanks for the suggestion tho.

Answer (score 0):

you can check this [trigger in oracle](https://www.oracletutorial.com/plsql-tutorial/oracle-trigger/#:%7E:text=%20How%20to%20create%20a%20trigger%20in%20Oracle,table%20associated%20with%20the%20trigger.%20%20More%20) and [creating trigger in oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45952997/creating-triggers-in-oracle). contains details on the types of trigger.
first link discuss the trigger structure header and body sections.
header section

```
CREATE [OR REPLACE] TRIGGER trigger_name
{BEFORE | AFTER } triggering_event ON table_name
[FOR EACH ROW]
[FOLLOWS | PRECEDES another_trigger]
[ENABLE / DISABLE ]
[WHEN condition]
```

body section

```
DECLARE
declaration statements
BEGIN
-- executable statements
EXCEPTION
-- exception statements
END;
```

the second link is to a que on SO.
make sure your trigger works on insert and update of student subject mark

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Std_report_trg
AFTER 
INSERT OR UPDATE
ON customers
FOR EACH ROW    
DECLARE
BEGIN
-- query here

END;
```

Comment: simple calculation before record is saved to db  or store procedure with the rstudent_id as param will works, but its your choose

Comment: Sorry, but this is not what I was looking for.